# When an individual makes a discovery

Tags: logic, consciousness, continental-philosophy

When an individual, or society as a whole, makes a discovery, different outcomes can occur e.g., they can enrich the individual *or*, they can debilitate the individual *or*, they can confront the individual, etc.

Are there certain final effects of discovery that are universal to those who undergo the process?

For example: *All* discoveries ultimately broaden the individuals understanding, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes, as they are either universally beneficial or universally harmful or both. For example the ability to split the atom was universally beneficial as it lead to many advances in all aspects of life from energy to medicine.

Also it could be considered universally harmful as the improper containment of the by-products / use of atomic material has impacted the globe!

Comment: I really like that viewpoint, it's a very simple way to analyze discovery, as it seems to be something that is so applicable as a definition to nearly every situation.